# Bundle products search/reset filter redirects to dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle, dashboard, reset-filter

SOLUTION BELOW

I have a problem when i'm trying to select some products for my bundle product. In the interface as seen below, i didn't get any products. After some Googling, i found out that i should click on "Reset filter" to get all products.

When i click on the "Reset filter" button, it redirected me to the dashboard. In my console there is a error.

"POST http://website.com/index.php/admin/bundle_selection/grid/index/0/key/f7390d1774b3bacf07841adce6c49fef/filter//?ajax=true&isAjax=true 503 (Service Unavailable)" in prototype.js:1530.

I've checked the version of prototype.js (1.7) and i have tried to update it to version 1.7.2. This has no effect. I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I hope that anyone could help me with this problem ;)
Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION:
I found the solution, in my var/report file was an error involving the Currency. It used an Array, not my currency (EUR). I didn't select an currency in the configuration properly. Thnx!

[image]

Comment: Your issue is not with prototype.js library, it's somewhere in the code, most likely due to some custom code or third-party module, because this should work properly by default. Check your `var/report` and `var/log` folders.

Comment: I found the solution, in my var/report file was an error involving the Currency. It used an Array, not my currency (EUR). I didn't select an currency in the configuration properly. Thnx!